# jQuery how to insert <br/> tag after every Semicolon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dumping some CSS into a div and I am looking to format it so it is more legible. Basically what I want to do is insert a break tag after every semicolon. I have searched around for a while but can't seem to find something that quite fits what I am trying to do.

I have something like this...

**HTML**

```
<div class='test'>
color:red;background-color:black;
</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
var test = $('.test').text();
var result = test.match(/;/g);   

alert(result);​
```

**And I have tried..**

```
var test = $('.test').text();
var result = test.match(/;/g);   

result.each(function(){
$('<br/>').insertAfter(';');
});    

alert(result);​
```

Also I have started a fiddle here.. Which basically just returns the matched character...
http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/zW3mj/9/
That is the only part I have been able to get to work so far.

I feel like I am sort of heading down the right path with this but I know it isn't right because it errors out. I am thinking there is a way to insert a break tag after each matched element, but I am not really sure how to get there. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Wouldn't the pre tag render the break tags as viewable code versus actually creating breaks like I want?

Comment: Thanks everybody for the very fast responses...

Comment: I was suggesting ommitting break tags altogether, and just pasting the css within the `<pre>` tags as you want it to be formatted. http://jsfiddle.net/NgHCE/

Comment: I have tried that... the problem is that is still doesn't format properly because the text is being dumped in via jQuery. So I think I would have to have it formatted before I dump it into the div. Otherwise as I understand it... The pre tag will render the code exactly how it is placed on the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try it like this

```
var test = $('.test').text();
var result = test.replace(/\;/g,';<br/>');   

$('.test').html(result);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sg5BB/

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to regex?

Comment: No actually, yeah, regex should be used here. My bad. :(

Comment: Generally, for small level stuffs, I thought we can use the basic syntax. :)

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification.. I picked some info up from your answer as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: In most other languages you would use a plain replace, but in Javascript that will only replace the first instance, so the use of the regular expression is just to use the `g` global flag.

Answer (score 3):

#### You can use a normal javascript `.replace()` method this way:

```
​$(document)​.ready(function(){
    $(".test").html($(".test").html().replace(/;/g, ";<br />"));
});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SPBTp/4/

Comment: No need of using regex for this small kind of application. `.replace()` method does the trick! :)

Comment: If you have more than one ';' you will need to use something similar to wirey. if you just use simple `.replace()` it will only replace the first instance. http://jsfiddle.net/SPBTp/2/

Answer (score 2):

Use This CODE

```
var test = $('.test').text();
var result = test.split(';').join(';<br />')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FmBpF/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use jQuery selectors on text, it only works on elements.

Get the text, just replace each `;` with `;<br/>`, and put it back.

```
$('.test').html($('.test').text().replace(/;/g, ';<br/>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

var test = $('.test').text();
var result = test.replace(/;/g,";
");
$('.test').html(result);
​
That should work if you stick it into your jfiddle.